# Disable "TLS Certificate revocation checks on" in Java for all users

Tags: security, java, certificate, tls

Apologies if this has been asked and I am a bit of newbie to Java.

We are currently running JRE 8  Update 211 32 bit (I know this is not the latest version) running in Windows 10.

I am currently trying to find the property key (definition) to disable TLS certificate revocation checks on to define in Deployment.Properties file.

I have managed to find part of it which is:

```
deployment.security.revocation.check=NO_CHECK
deployment.security.revocation.check.locked
```

Which did the following:

[Java Control Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrJRt.png)

As you can see the from the screenshot I managed to implement the setting for side code certificate revocation but unable to find the code for TLS certificate revocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the post
[Java control panel setting](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2302548-java-control-panel-setting)
these settings seem to be:

```
deployment.security.tls.revocation.check=NO_CHECK
deployment.security.tls.revocation.check. Locked
```

Comment: Thanks that sorted it.